# Error when trying to add authentication annotations in loopback 4

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4

I want to add authentication to my server. I followed the docs here: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Authentication-tutorial.html

When I add this annotation `@authenticate('jwt')` I get the following error:

```
Cannot start the application. TypeError: core_1.injectable is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mshaham\projects\mevolve\user-service\node_modules\@loopback\authentication\src\providers\auth-action.provider.ts:116:2)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mshaham\projects\mevolve\user-service\node_modules\@loopback\authentication\src\providers\index.ts:6:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xxxxx\projects\xxxx\user-service\node_modules\@loopback\authentication\src\authentication.component.ts:8:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)
```

Comment: What version of Node.js?

Comment: @RifaAchrinza v13.10.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue. I installed loopback authentication package several weeks after installing loopback core. Meanwhile, the core package had a release with breaking changes.

So, all I had to do was update my packages using `npm update` and problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Node.js v13 is not officially supported by LoopBack 4 nor by [the Node.js team themselves](https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/). It's also advised to stick to even-numbered or LTS versions.

Change the Node.js runtime to either `v10`, `v12`, or `v14`.